# How to write text to temp file?

Tags: python, list, file, for-loop, temporary-files

I'm trying to write some text to a tempfile, but it doesn't work for some reason. When I'm printing `print(tmp.readlines())` I only get an empty list.

As you can see I'm first looping through `sentences.txt` and writing every sentence that doesn't match `"I like cars."` to the tmp file. Then I want to write those sentences back to `sentences.txt`, so I'm basically filtering the `sentences.txt` file.

```
with open("sentences.txt") as file:
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode="w+") as tmp:
        for line in file:
            if line.rstrip() != "I like cars.":
                tmp.write(line + "\n")
        with open("sentences.txt", "a") as f:
            for line in tmp:
                f.write(line + "\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are writing to a file and then trying to read from the same file. You need to have `tmp.seek(0)` before `for line in tmp` to reset the file pointer (`tmp`) to the start of the file

Comment: But the problem is that `tmp.write()` doesn't work.

Comment: @Nicke7117 how are you so sure that `tmp.write()` doesn't work? As i stated in my answer you need to have `tmp.seek(0)` to read from the same file you wrote stuff to. I updated my answer it was `f.seek` but should have been `tmp.seek`